# Connect() does not work

Tags: c++, winsock

I am following a c++ networking tutorial, [winsock](http://www.madwizard.org/programming/tutorials/netcpp/).

But my code I have written so far does not entirely work, what am I doing wrong?

```
my "main.cpp"

#include "main.h"

using namespace std;

int winsock()
{

    //variables

    const int winsock_version = 2;

    WSAData wsa;

    SOCKET sok;

    SOCKADDR_IN server;

    //start up
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(winsock_version,0), &wsa);

    sok = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    //check startup
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(winsock_version,0), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        cout << "An error occured during startup! \n";
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }

    //check version
    if (LOBYTE(wsa.wVersion)  < winsock_version)
    {
        cout << "Your version of winsock is too low!\n";
        cout << "\nWinsock 2.0 or above is required.";
        return -1;
    }

    //check if socket is valid
    if (sok == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Invalid socket!";
        return -1;
    }

    //set connection type
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    //set port
    server.sin_port = htons(80);
    //set adress to connect to
    server.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;


    //connect
    connect(sok,(sockaddr*)(&server), sizeof(server));
    //bind socket
    bind(sok, (sockaddr*)(&server), sizeof(server));

    if(connect(sok,(sockaddr*)(&server), sizeof(server)) !=0)
    {
        cout << "error during connecting! \n";
        WSACleanup();
        closesocket(sok);
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Connection was made!";
    //clean up
    WSACleanup();
    closesocket(sok);
    if (WSACleanup() !=0 || closesocket(sok) !=0)
    {
        cout << "Clean up failed! \n";
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    winsock();
}
```

and my "main.h"

```
#ifndef MAIN_H_INCLUDED
#define MAIN_H_INCLUDED

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif


// std libs
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


//windows
#include <windows.h>
//networking libs
#include <winsock2.h>
// layout engine

#endif // MAIN_H_INCLUDED
```

When I run the program it says "error during connecting!", so that means I have some kind of error.

I use code::blocks as my IDE.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot connect to `INADDR_ANY`. Specify a IP address.

Why are you calling `WSAStartup()` twice?

And you don't have to use `bind()` to perform a `connect()` unless its strictily important that your local port must be specified (like in SMB protocol).

There are plenty of [exemples on how to use WinSock to connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), read them.

Comment: The tutorial i am following says it is possible, www.madwizard.org/programming/tutorials/netcpp/4

Comment: I am talking about INADDR_ANY

Comment: When you try to connect to something you must be specific about the address and protocol otherwise it's meaningless. For listen it's meaningful since it means "accept connection from anywhere", for connect it would mean "connect to anywhere"?!

Comment: No, you can never connect to this address. `INADDR_ANY` is to be used with `listen()` only. It means you are opening a port and accepting connections from any IP or interface you have, because you are not specifying one. It literally means the IP `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: @user2875871: you have misread the tutorial.  You can *bind* to INADDR_ANY and thereby listen for incoming connections on all the machine's network interfaces (section 6), but you cannot connect to INADDR_ANY (section 5).